# Joining results of a block into an array without a temp variable?

Tags: ruby

I am currently using the following code:

```
text = "a, 1; b, 2"
temp = []
text.gsub(/\s+/, "").split(";").each {|x| temp << x.split(",")}
temp # => [["a","1"],["b","2"]]
```

I'm wondering if there is slick way to get this done all in one line without the extra `temp = []` line? How would one join the result of each block execution into an array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html) module is a must-read for any Ruby novice. Use [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) instead:

```
text.gsub(/\s+/, "").split(";").map { |x| x.split(",") }
#=> [["a", "1"], ["b", "2"]]
```

It appears you're not familiar with the functional programming principles, here it's a [link](http://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming) it may help you (specifically: [see this](http://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming#init-empty_+_each_+_push_=_map)). Every time you write a `each` think if there is some alternative (it's ok to do a side-effect like writing a file, but it's usually a bad idea to update a variable).

Comment: `text.split("; ").map { |x| x.split(", ") }` , avoiding an extra string, is an option.

Comment: @tokland Thank you! Do you (or others) know of a set of exercises (textbook-like) for one to use to practice these functional programming techniques in Ruby or any other language?

Comment: "Ruby best practices" has a chapter on FP: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/ruby/9780596157487/functional-programming-techniques/i_sect15_d1e7222. Check also this great video: http://vimeo.com/6701329. Ruby is not a functional language so there is not a lot of material. You can always learn Haskell or Erlang or Scala or OCaml.

Answer (score 1):

For the very limited corpus you provided, you can do use *#scan* to parse the string into an array, and then convert a series of slices into sub-arrays. For example:

```
"a, 1; b, 2".scan(/\w+/).each_slice(2).to_a
=> [["a", "1"], ["b", "2"]]
```

Whether or not this is useful in a more general sense is up to you.